# Deploy python app to Heroku "Slug Size too large"

Tags: python, tensorflow, heroku, tensorflow2.0

I'm trying to deploy a Streamlit app written in python to Heroku. My whole directory is 4.73 MB, where 4.68 MB is my ML model. My `requirements.txt` looks like this:

```
absl-py==0.9.0
altair==4.0.1
astor==0.8.1
attrs==19.3.0
backcall==0.1.0
base58==2.0.0
bleach==3.1.3
blinker==1.4
boto3==1.12.29
botocore==1.15.29
cachetools==4.0.0
certifi==2019.11.28
chardet==3.0.4
click==7.1.1
colorama==0.4.3
cycler==0.10.0
decorator==4.4.2
defusedxml==0.6.0
docutils==0.15.2
entrypoints==0.3
enum-compat==0.0.3
future==0.18.2
gast==0.2.2
google-auth==1.11.3
google-auth-oauthlib==0.4.1
google-pasta==0.2.0
grpcio==1.27.2
h5py==2.10.0
idna==2.9
importlib-metadata==1.5.2
ipykernel==5.2.0
ipython==7.13.0
ipython-genutils==0.2.0
ipywidgets==7.5.1
jedi==0.16.0
Jinja2==2.11.1
jmespath==0.9.5
joblib==0.14.1
jsonschema==3.2.0
jupyter-client==6.1.1
jupyter-core==4.6.3
Keras-Applications==1.0.8
Keras-Preprocessing==1.1.0
kiwisolver==1.1.0
Markdown==3.2.1
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
matplotlib==3.2.1
mistune==0.8.4
nbconvert==5.6.1
nbformat==5.0.4
notebook==6.0.3
numpy==1.18.2
oauthlib==3.1.0
opencv-python==4.2.0.32
opt-einsum==3.2.0
pandas==1.0.3
pandocfilters==1.4.2
parso==0.6.2
pathtools==0.1.2
pickleshare==0.7.5
Pillow==7.0.0
prometheus-client==0.7.1
prompt-toolkit==3.0.4
protobuf==3.11.3
pyasn1==0.4.8
pyasn1-modules==0.2.8
pydeck==0.3.0b2
Pygments==2.6.1
pyparsing==2.4.6
pyrsistent==0.16.0
python-dateutil==2.8.0
pytz==2019.3
pywinpty==0.5.7
pyzmq==19.0.0
requests==2.23.0
requests-oauthlib==1.3.0
rsa==4.0
s3transfer==0.3.3
scikit-learn==0.22.2.post1
scipy==1.4.1
Send2Trash==1.5.0
six==1.14.0
sklearn==0.0
streamlit==0.56.0
tensorboard==2.1.1
tensorflow==2.1.0
tensorflow-estimator==2.1.0
termcolor==1.1.0
terminado==0.8.3
testpath==0.4.4
toml==0.10.0
toolz==0.10.0
tornado==5.1.1
traitlets==4.3.3
tzlocal==2.0.0
urllib3==1.25.8
validators==0.14.2
watchdog==0.10.2
wcwidth==0.1.9
webencodings==0.5.1
Werkzeug==1.0.0
widgetsnbextension==3.5.1
wincertstore==0.2
wrapt==1.12.1
zipp==3.1.0
```

When I push my app to Heroku, the message is:

```
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types -> web
remote:
remote: -----> Compressing...
remote:  !     Compiled slug size: 623.5M is too large (max is 500M).
remote:  !     See: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/slug-size
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
```

How can my slug size be too large? Is it the size of the requirements? Then how is it possible to deploy a python app using tensorflow to Heroku after all?
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Tensorflow can be run on Heroku. For very small application it can be okay but during runtime you will run into memory problem. You can solve the memory problem by paying for Heroku services thus getting more RAM. The resulting size of your slug is normal. Machine learning is complicated and requires a lot of code. It gets even bigger during runtime.

Comment: I would recommend to check the Heroku Slug that your build script produces. There could be an accidentally left over large file/folder (e.g. .git folder for large projects

Answer (score 61, accepted):

*I have already answered this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62356779/11105967).*

Turns out the Tensorflow 2.0 module is very large (more than 500MB, the limit for Heroku) because of its GPU support. Since Heroku doesn't support GPU, it doesn't make sense to install the module with GPU support.

### Solution:

Simply replace **tensorflow** with **tensorflow-cpu** in your requirements.

This worked for me, hope it works for you too!

Comment: Thats great. I was dealing with the slug size by hours but just changing "tensorflow" by "tensorflow-cpu" in requirements  the md decreased like 200 md. Thanks you!

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks a ton.

Comment: This saved my life. I use Tensorflow 2.4.x before and it's size nearly 500 MB. Cange to `tensorflow-cpu` it's only 144 MB

Comment: Hi, do i need to only update tensorflow in the requirements.txt? There are some other ones lik tensorboard,tensorboard-data-server,
tensorboard-plugin-wit etc which are automatically installed when i installed tensorflow in my local

Comment: Whatever you dream should come true. Thank you @SuryaChereddy

Answer (score 5):

In `requirements.txt` file, I replaced `tensorflow==2.6.0` to `tensorflow-cpu==2.6.0` and it worked perfectly

Comment: Working one. It decreased almost 300MB for me, from 680 to 380

Answer (score 2):

Just replace your TensorFlow version to 2.0.0 by doing: 
`tensorflow==2.0.0`
It has a much lighter whl file and will fit your memory limit.
Also, you can use 1.7.0 or 1.5.0 versions.

Comment: I am getting No matching distribution found for tensorflow==2.0.0

Answer (score 1):

just use `tensorflow` version `1.14` as it is almost half the size of tf2.0+ and servers most purposes.
In my case the slug size almost halved from `tf1.14(580MB)` at place of `tf.2.1(280MB)`

Answer (score -2):

it means when downloaded all your requirements are summing upto 600mb but you have only 500mb of memory

Comment: Yeah, I know that. But I'm asking if there is any other possibility to deploy a Tensorflow app to Heroku without paying if the dependency alone kills the Slug size, but apparently it isn't