# Flask web app with Tensorflow on Heroku. Error: Slug Size too large

Tags: python, tensorflow, heroku, keras

I'm trying to deploy a web app that has some image prediction in it using tensorflow and keras. The tensorflow package itself is like 400mb and that doesn't include my .h5 file. Is there anyway I can publish my site on Heroku or any other site that would be better. Total Heroku says it's about 620mb. Thanks!

Comment: Here are your options https://stackoverflow.com/a/65787615/9095551

Answer (score 0):

In requirements.txt, if you specify a lower version of tensorflow like tensorflow==2.0.1 or tensorflow==1.7.0, the size of the compressed file in heroku is reduced drastically to 200 to 300 MB.Try this and check. Let me know if it works or not. Thanks and have a great day